# Установила расширение C/C++ для VSCode

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

MinGW добавила в путь, вызвала в командной строке gcc, g++ и gdb,все работает. Пытаюсь запустить,направляет в launch.json, не видит ничего.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Скачайте расширение для C++, созданное Microsoft, а затем перезапустите VS Code